# How to solve this integral equation with the Dirichlet kernel?

Tags: integral-equations

It is

$$  S (t) = 1  - i g \int_0^t d \tau \left( \sum_{n=-M}^M e^{-i n (t- \tau )} \right) S(\tau) . $$

The kernel is the Dirichlet kernel. Numerical result is shown in the figure.

The $M\rightarrow \infty $ limit is easy (because the kernel reduces to a series of delta functions). In this limit, $S$ is a piece-wise constant function, illustrated by the red lines. But for a finite $M$, you will always get the fast rotation whose amplitude does not decay to zero in the limit of $M \rightarrow \infty $. Its amplitude converges to a finite value actually.

The purpose is not to get the analytical expression of $S $ (it might does not exist), but to understand qualitatively its behavior.

[image]

Comment: What does "$g$" represent?

Comment: a real  constant

Comment: It cannot be an arbitrary constant.  What were you given here?

Answer (score 2):

Nice solenoids...:)

What follows is not a full answer, but hopefully may help

- 1) Have you tried to take the Fourier **Transform** of LHS and RHS (the RHS is clearly a convolution) ?
- 2) As the Dirichlet kernel is a way to work on partial sums of Fourier **series**, when you say "converges to a finite value", I am almost sure that it has something to do with the Gibbs' phenomenon and its quantization (overshoot by $\approx 0.09 \%$) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon)
- 3) Besides, have a look at "The good, the bad and the ugly of kernels: why the
  Dirichlet kernel is not a good kernel"(https://www.google.fr/search?q=good+ugly+kernels+Dirichlet&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=n74uV-TpDKus8weJgoS4DQ)

Comment: I wondered if the particular results you find are not because, using $\int_0^t \cdots$, you implicitely work with "causal" functions, and in particular with $U(t)D_M(t)$ ($U(t)$ = Heaviside, $D_M$ = Dirichlet) instead of $D_M(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel can be written

$$\sum_{n=-M}^M e^{in(t-\tau)}=\frac{\sin\left((M+1/2)(t-\tau)\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12(t-\tau)\right)}$$

The kernel has zeroes when $t-\tau=\frac{2\ell \pi}{2M+1}$, $\ell \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\ell \ne (2M+1)m$, for $m\in \mathbb{Z}$.  When $t-\tau\to 2m\pi$, we have

$$\lim_{t-\tau\to 2m\pi }\left(\frac{\sin\left((M+1/2)(t-\tau)\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12(t-\tau)\right)}\right)=2M+1$$

for $m\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Next, note that the limit, $\lim_{M\to \infty}\left(\frac{\sin\left((M+1/2)(t-\tau)\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12(t-\tau)\right)}\right)$, does not exist.   However, we can evaluate

$$\lim_{M\to \infty} \int_0^t \sum_{n=-M}^M e^{in(t-\tau)}\,S(\tau)\,d\tau$$

using the approach I presented in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767590/find-sin-frac-pi3-frac12-sin-frac2-pi3-frac13-sin-frac3-pi/1767679#1767679).    Proceeding analogously, we have for $0\le t<2\pi$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^t \sum_{n=-M}^M e^{in(t-\tau)}\,S(\tau)\,d\tau&=\int_0^t\frac{\sin\left((M+1/2)(t-\tau)\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12(t-\tau)\right)}S(\tau)\,d\tau\\\\
&=2\int_0^{(2M+1)t/2}\frac{\sin(x)}{(2M+1)\sin\left(\frac{x}{2M+1}\right)}S\left(t+\frac{2x}{2M+1}\right)\,dx\\\\
&\to \pi S(t)\,\,\text{as}\,\,M\to \infty \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Note that if $2k\pi <t<2(k+1)\pi$, then $(1)$ becomes

$$\lim_{M\to \infty}\int_0^t \sum_{n=-M}^M e^{in(t-\tau)}\,S(\tau)\,d\tau=\pi\left(\sum_{j=1}^k S(2j\pi)+S(t)\right)$$

Comment: Could it be possible to obtain your final result by using the fact that the limit of Dirichlet kernel when $M \rightarrow \infty$ is Dirac comb (See $ http://www.theoretical-physics.net/dev/math/transforms.html) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, of course.  I wanted to avoid using the Theory of Generalized Functions and stick with classical analysis.  ;-)) -Mark